# How to set css class for Rails date_select year select?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this bit of code:

```
= f.date_select :dateofbirth, :start_year => Date.current.year, :end_year => 1930, :html=>{:class => "choose_dateofbirth"}
```

where I'd like to set a class to the year select only, can that be done and if so - how?

Note that at current state it doesn't set any class to any select field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

`:with_css_classes => true`

Set to true if you want assign different styles for 'select' tags. This option automatically set classes 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute' and 'second' for your 'select' tags.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select

Answer (score 4):

this should work

```
= f.date_select :dateofbirth, {:start_year => Date.current.year, :end_year => 1930}, {class: "choose_dateofbirth"}
```

[docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select)

```
date_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```